# xkb swap backslash and return: how to deal with shift?

Tags: xkb, setxkbmap

I'm trying to swap Enter and Backslash key. I figured out how to swap them when Shift is not involved:

key < RTRN > {[ backslash ]};

key < BKSL > {[ Return ]};

However, when shift is down, by pressing Enter I got "", whereas I would like to have "|" there. And vice versa, by pressing Backslash I got "|", whereas I would like to have Enter (just as without shift).

How to define keys for Shift? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `key < RTRN > {[ backslash, bar ]};` `key < BKSL > {[ Return, Return ]};`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.